# What versions of java are slow for gc logging?

Tags: java, performance, logging, garbage-collection, jvm

I've been told by my company's support team that some versions of java have a significant performance impact when we turn on `-verbose:gc`.  However I can't figure out if this is the case or not.

Was this logging slow(ish) at some point, and when did it stop?

The reason I ask is that there's some hesitation about applying this to a production environment to investigate potential memory leaks (and whether we can stop doing periodic restarts of the system...).

*Specifically I'm talking about Java 1.4.2 which I think introduced the argument, and what service pack it applies up to.*

Comment: Is that what They say? In my experience, half the time They have no idea what They are talking about. In the absence of evidence, such claims are merely gossip.

Comment: This particular support person is reliable enough make this warrant further investigation. There is however, a chance that it was simply some other aspect of garbage collection that can be changed to heavily impact performance. I certainly can't remember that far back.

Comment: I fear you mistook my point. I have no doubt your support person believed that to be true, and of course logging will always be slower than not logging. You've not mentioned why you care, so the question could be expressed as other than a historical curiosity which will yield a more direct answer.

Comment: This is most certainly bogus - I worked in an organization for 10 years porting the JVM to various platforms, there is no slowdown when running verbose:gc on any 1.4.2 JVM.

Comment: @msw - it's for checking a memory leak in a production system.  We don't want to affect the environment

Comment: @Amir - make it an answer and you get some rep :)

Comment: Accepting every word of Mr. Afghani's comment (and I have no reason not to, so I choose to believe it) it is still only an anecdote which isn't evidence. If you are attempting to use SO to prove a point to your operations staff, they have every right to laugh in your face, and probably should; were I in their shoes, I'd demand a quantitative analysis of the relative impact before altering my production environment, and I would - by definition - be right.

Comment: I agree with the above comment, and the posted answers.  In order to provide evidence, you'll need to run some microbenchmarks.  SPECjbb, SPECjvm98, and the monster of them all, SPECjAppServer.  Good luck, and do post an update on your findings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest that you do the following:

1. Write some benchmark that is likely to stress the garbage collection.  (Create large linked data structures with weak references, etc, etc).
2. Install a copy of the same version of the JVM as you are using in production on some test box.
3. Run the benchmark with various GC logging settings, including the settings that you want to run in production, measuring the performance impact on the benchmark.

If you do this right, it will give you some solid evidence about what the likely performance impact will be for your production server.

Answer (score 5):

I know you asked about the impact of verbose:gc (Amir is correct), but based on the comments I see you are investigating a memory leak.

Is it possible for you to get a histogram of your environment? verbose GC will only show you that there is a memory leak, not where the memory is sitting.

you mention java 1.4.2, is that your current version? If you are using 1.5 or higher you can use

```
jmap -histo <pid> > file.txt
```

This will give you a breakdown of all the objects in memory. You will freeze your JVM for a time dependent on the amount of memory in the system. (2GB can freeze for a minute or so on even good hardware) test this on a development system first. I know you don't want to impact your production environment but this is a necessary evil to find the source of the problem. Do a capture right before the periodic restart to lesson your impact.